# How to find the distance between two points on a sphere in polar coordinates with fixed $\phi$

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-geometry

I'm trying to calculate the distance between to points on a sphere with fixed $\phi$. For clarity, the sphere has radius $R$ and is centered at the origin. So, if we let $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$, then clearly the distance between those two points is just $2R$, and if we let $\phi = 0$, then the distance is just $0$. Apparently, the distance is given by $2R\sin\phi$ in polar coordinates. This makes sense to me intuitively, as in the examples above, $\sin\phi$ would be $1$ and $0$ respectively, but I can't seem to make sense of the $\phi$ values in between. I'm guessing some sort of trig is required. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you come up with $2R \sin(\varphi)$? If you are just interested in the distance of two points( on the sphere) in say $\mathbb{R}^2$, why don't you work with the usual metric, i.e $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The 2Rsin(phi) came from Khan Academy, in an article about a geometric derivation of the Jacobian in spherical coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* the questioner wants to ask this question:

**If a plane perpendicular to the $z$ axis cuts a sphere of radius $R$ so as to subtend elevation angle $\phi$, what is the diameter of the circle of intersection?**

[image]

This diameter is obviously $2 R \sin \phi$ (blue).

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not quite what I meant. Imagine slicing the sphere along the z axis. What would the diameter of a given slice if we know the z axis, or equivalently if we know the polar angle?

Comment: "Imagine slicing the sphere along the z axis". Do you mean cutting the sphere vertically through its center?  Please draw a figure.

Comment: I mean slicing perpendicularly to the z axis

Comment: But my figure shows precisely that!  The red contour lies on a slice of the sphere at a constant $\phi$.  PLEASE draw a figure!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I was a little unclear. Your figure is what I want, I see that now. But I'm not sure how to use your diagram. I want to find the diameter of the circle that you can fit onto the slice.

Comment: Now that you updated it, that is exactly what I wanted. I'm sorry for being so unclear, I can understand your frustration. I was just confused. But yeah, I get it now, thanks a lot :) I will accept your answer.